# Installing Recaptcha in Joomla 1.5 user registration

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.5, recaptcha

I am trying to install ReCaptcha into the user registration of Joomla 1.5. This may just be an issue with Joomla but when i hit register nothing happens. I think it's doing some JavaScript form validation but there is nothing telling the user what went wrong. if, God forbid, they do fill out the form correctly Joomla will redirect the user to the homepage and give no notice of success.

Is this a Joomla issue or is there something wrong with my install? Does anyone know of a plug-in or module for Joomla that would make this easier?

Thanks in advance,
Samuel

UPDATE: Joomla does a lot of "stuff"/"something" to the $_POST and $_GET variables which was causing the reCaptcha to not function. This was for work which is past so I am not spending anymore time on it. Shameless Plug: use wordpress instead.

*this can be closed as I don't have time to verify which answer works*

Comment: this was asked in july..i guess someone should close it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joomla does a lot of "stuff"/"something" to the $_POST and $_GET variables which was causing the reCaptcha to not function. This was for work which is past so I am not spending anymore time on it.

using wordpress from now on.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you tried all reCaptcha plugins for Joomla? There are plenty:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/search/reCaptcha

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your template contains the message tag to display messages to the user regarding successful or unsuccessful registrations (among other things!)

http://docs.joomla.org/Jdoc_statements

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that no error is displayed ? Iam using it with some php applications, the error is inside the "BOX".

Comment: I don't think the issue is with recaptcha not displaying an error. It's that Joomla isn't submiting the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try the community builder component, module.

Answer (score 0):

If by 'nothing happens' you mean the visitor stays on the registration page and doesn't advance, check the JavaScript error log for your browser and ensure that a fatal error isn't keeping the form from being submitted. If you mean that the page does advance and the result is a completely blank page, there may be a PHP error being encountered, and you have errors not being publicly displayed. Log into the hosting server and look at the PHP log to see if there's any fatal errors showing up.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend using mollom/moovum. It works with registration and the beautiful thing is that you don't have to hack any files while users will only notice your protection if there is doubt or spam.